# How to solve Error creating subscription in the context broker server: Connection Error?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-wirecloud

I'm trying to retrieve data from Orion context broker in Wirecloud via NGSI Source Operator. I run Orion broker in a VM-Centos.

The NGSI server URL is "http://192.168.2.129:1026".

The NGSI proxy URL is "https://ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org".

The error "Error creating subscription in the context broker server: Connection Error' . What should i do?
Providing that when i write the IP in the browser, that's the result:

```
{
"orionError" : 
   {
   "code" : "400",
   "reasonPhrase" : "Bad Request", 
   "details" : "service not found"
   }
}
```

The url is in the VM of the CB With the IP and port of the CB VM https://postimg.org/image/qgi5rlm1z/

The Error: "Error creating subscription in the context broker server: Connection Error” appears in the wiring on the wirecloud
The overall idea is that I have created entities successfully, I can register, update, sub and query But I need to see these results on the wirecloud..so I need to retrieve the data from the VM to the wirecloud to be visible on the NSGI browser Widget.

When I make the NSGI proxy setting to : https://ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org →  "Error creating subscription in the context broker server: Connection Error” https://s31.postimg.org/q50pe9d5n/image.png

When I change it to : https://mashup.lab.fiware.org:8443 → This appears https://s31.postimg.org/4ilox86vf/image.png

Wiring : https://s31.postimg.org/od7qjced7/image.png

Comment: Specify how is your request...

Comment: This bad Request occurs when i typed the  VM IP address in the browser, in order to check if there is any request occurring

Comment: You have to follow the Orion NGSI API... to test your access, you can use `http://192.168.2.129:1026/version` or, if you have already some created entities, you can try `http://192.168.2.129:1026/v2/entities`, and so on...

Comment: @AdhamElmasry I have the same problem here, `Error creating subscription in the context broker server:  Connection Error` using my deployed instance of Orion CB. How did you solve this problem please?

Answer (score 0):

if you just type in the browser

http://192.168.2.129:1026 you will get the error you describe as no Orion service is invoked.

If you want to create a subscription you would need to do it directly to the Broker without passing through the NGSI Proxy. So you would need to

POST http://192.168.2.129:1026/v2/subscriptions using a payload similar to the one described at

http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/walkthrough_apiv2/index.html#subscriptions

I Hope this helps